# Requirement for a given function to be smooth

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions, logarithms

I have quite a basic question about the derivatives. My uncertainty comes mainly from the fact that I don't know how the complex logarithm behaves. Here is the description (this task is not homework!):

Assume I have a (complex) function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, and I want to find a real, *smooth* function $\theta$ such that $\tilde{f}:=e^{i\theta}f$ is real, i.e. I just rotate $f$.

Now, my question is: which properties do I have to impose on $f$ and $\tilde{f}$ such that such smooth function $\theta$ exists?

*Attempt at the solution*:

$\tilde{f}=e^{i\theta}f$

$\log(\tilde{f})=i\theta+i2\pi n+\log(f)$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

$i\theta=\log(\tilde{f})-i2\pi n-\log(f)$

$\theta=-2\pi n-i(\log(\tilde{f})-\log(f))$

Now I'm not sure how to proceed from here. $\log(\tilde{f})$ is real but $\log(f)$ is complex. If I want $\theta$ to be smooth then the right hand side also has to be smooth. Which properties does it then imply for $f,\tilde{f}$?

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? I imagine $f:\Bbb{C}\to \Bbb{C}$. In that case wouldn't you like $\theta:\Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{R}$  ( the angle you need to rotate $f(z)$ should depend on $z$)? that is not what $C^\infty(\Bbb{R})$ means...

Comment: @ConradoCosta thank you for the comment, I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of constructing an angle function is rather lengthy but the key point is to keep track of how many complete turns we have made around $0$.

If $F$ is smooth then you can obtain a smooth $\theta$.

But note that you can consider discontinuous functions and still have a smooth $\theta$. For instance $G(t) = F^{it} + \delta_{(0,\infty)}(F(t))$

To construct a smooth angle function from a smooth $F$ It is sufficient to decompose your function $F(t) = r(F(t)) e^{i g(F(t))}= r(F(t)) e^{i h(F(t))}$ where $g(z)$ is the angle measured in counter-clockwise manner beginning at the positive real axis ($g(z) \in[0,2 \pi)$) and $h(z)$ is the angle measured counter-clockwise manner beginning at the negative real  axis ($h(z) \in[-\pi,\pi)$).Note that $$g(z) = h(z) + 2 k(z)\pi $$ and  that $g\circ F,h \circ F$ are not  smooth functions in general ( look at $F(t) = e^{it}$ - Note that $\theta(t) = t$ is smooth)

Note also that $g(z)$ is smooth as long as $z \in \Bbb{C} \setminus \{z  \mid\Re(z) <0, \Im(z)=0 \} = A_g$ and that $h(z)$ is smooth as long as $z \in \Bbb{C} \setminus \{z  \mid\Re(z) >0, \Im(z)=0 \} = A_h$.

Assume withou loss that $F(0) \in A_g$ So you can consider $\theta(0) = g(F(0))$ as long as $F(0)\in A_g$ but once you "approach" $\{z  \mid\Re(z) <0, \Im(z)=0 \}$ you need to consider $\theta(t) = h(F(t)) + 2k(z)\pi $

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for the answer. I hope I didn't misunderstand though: you are construction smooth $\theta$ from the *decomposition* of $f$, right? Well, I didn't want to decompose $f$ and look for a smooth angle there, rather multiply it by *external* function $e^{i\theta}$ so that the whole expression becomes real. Did I misunderstand your argument? @Conrado Costa

Comment: Once you decompose $F(t) = r(F(t)) e^{i \theta(F(t))}$ you can make it real by multiplying in the following way: $e^{-i \theta F(t)}F(t) = r(F(t))$.

Comment: so then in your notation, does r(F(t)) mean the real part? @Conrado Costa

Comment: no $r(F(t))$ is the norm of $F(t)$ $r^2(z) = a^2+ b^2$ when $z = a+ ib$

Comment: ah, I see, so my $\tilde{f}$ is then exactly $e^{-i\theta F(t)}F(t)$, that is, the smooth function I'm looking for is $-\theta F(t)$ (what I called just $\theta$), right?

Comment: Yes, there is a minus sign to adjust things.

Comment: super, thank you very much!

Comment: I forgot to mention, but it is important that $F(t)\neq 0$ consider for exemple $F(t) = t+ i t$ the angle is $+ 45^o$ and suddenly shifts to $135^o$ arround $t = 0$

Comment: thank you. Just as a point of interest: so it's not possible to resolve this problem in the way that I started, i.e. just by taking the logarithm of both sides? @Conrado Costa

Comment: Complex logarithm is an object that depends on the choice on how you measure angle in the region. There are many complex logarithms none of them in analytic in the entire region $\Bbb{C}$ and the reason for this (you might already suspect) is that once you give a $360^o$ turn, the angle is the same. That would produce a discontinuity. look at this picture http://william-wright.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/escher.jpg