# Lifting smooth function $f:M\to S^1$ to a function $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, manifolds, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces

Suppose that I have a smooth function $f:M\to S^1$ for a connected manifold $M$. I know that $p:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ defined by $p(t) = e^{i t}$ is a covering map and that $\mathbb{R}$ is the universal cover of $S^1$. I am interested in what conditions I can put on $M$ such that if $f:M\to S^1$ is smooth, then there exists a smooth function $\tilde{f}:M\to \mathbb{R}$ so that $f = p\circ \tilde{f}$.

In this answer: [Requirement for a given function to be smooth](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371268/requirement-for-a-given-function-to-be-smooth) it seems to be implied that if $M = \mathbb{R}$, then the result should hold. I am thinking that it might suffice to assume that $M$ is simply connected so that it does not have a universal cover other than itself.

Another user made this post: [When is it possible to lift a function to its covering space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438169/when-is-it-possible-to-lift-a-function-to-its-covering-space) which gives an equivalent condition for when we can have this lift property, but my Algebra/Category Theory is quite weak so I am unsure what conditions on $M$ will satisfy the condition. I am thinking that if $M$ is simply connected, then $\pi_1(M) = \{0\}$ so the condition should be satisfied.

My question could also be phrased as, if $f:M\to \mathbb{C}$ has constant magnitude so that $|f| = C > 0$, then does there exist a smooth function $g:M\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f = e^{ig}$. A little bit of direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider reading an Algebraic Topology textbook? For instance, both Hatcher and Massey address this issue.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have just gotten overwhelmed when trying to read thatcher. I will try it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist lifting of a map $X \to Y$ to a covering $\tilde Y\to Y$ if an only if the image of $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ is inside the image of $\pi_1(\tilde Y, \tilde y_0)$.

So in our case, we would need the image of $\pi_1(M)$ trivial. It surely is so if $M$ is simply connected.

Comment: Wonderful. So since $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}) = \{0\}$, $M$ being simply connected is precisely the condition we need?

Comment: @Andrew Shedlock: $M$ simply connected is sufficient.  But imagine that we are lifting a constant map ( always possible), even if $M$ is *not* simply connected.

Comment: @AndrewShedlock What matters is that $f$ trivialises all loops. This doesn’t need $M$ to be simply connected. NOTE: the fact that $M$ is a connected manifold is used here! The lifting theorem requires certain hypotheses, iirc the space $M$ needs to be locally and globally path connected. This is true for connected manifolds; counterexamples exist otherwise.

Comment: @FShrike Exactly. I am specifically looking at the case for maps from connected manifolds so the assumptions on our domain will hold. But it makes sense for general topological spaces it will not be equivalent.